# How to view partial area of a treeview and horizontal scrollable in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

I have a table created by tk.treeview, for example, there're 10 columns. The target is to build a treeview widget with horizontal scrollbar, the view width of widget is set just about 4 columns and use horizontal scrollbar to view other columns.

Using tk.Frame as parent widget and with scrollbar, vertical scroll will hide the header, so not use it.

Platform: WIN 10
Python: 3.8.6
tkinter: 8.6

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

# root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
# root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

columns = [f'Column {i}' for i in range(10)]

x_scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(root, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL)
x_scrollbar.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=tk.E+tk.W)
y_scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(root, orient=tk.VERTICAL)
y_scrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tk.N+tk.S)

tree = ttk.Treeview(root, columns=columns, height=10, show="headings",
    xscrollcommand=x_scrollbar.set, yscrollcommand=y_scrollbar.set)
tree.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.N+tk.S+tk.E+tk.W)

for col in tree['columns']:
        tree.heading(col, text=f"{col}", anchor=tk.CENTER)
        tree.column(col, anchor=tk.CENTER, width=100)

for i in range(100):
    tree.insert('', 'end', values=[i*10+j for j in range(len(columns))])

x_scrollbar['command'] = tree.xview
y_scrollbar['command'] = tree.yview

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

The question is how can I set the view width just about 4 columns and with horizontal scrollbar work ? like this ! (no windiw resize)

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a tricky way to do it:

- initially set the column widths to a smaller size, for your case it is 40 (i.e. 400 / 10)
- force update the treeview using `tree.update()`
- set the column widths to the desired size, i.e. 100

```py
for col in tree['columns']:
    tree.heading(col, text=f"{col}", anchor=tk.CENTER)
    tree.column(col, anchor=tk.CENTER, width=40) # initially smaller size
tree.update()
for col in tree['columns']:
    tree.column(col, width=100) # restore to desired size
```

Comment: It work ! Not sure what happen ? it seems that `tree.update()` set the window size, and new width set for tree column won't change the window size, event in mainloop() ? no more update ? I added one more `tree.update()` and it still work.

Comment: Yes, after the treeview is laid out (via `tree.update()`) the treeview size will not be affected by changing column widths.

Comment: Good, even I don't know where you got it. I spend two day and you help me in few seconds, thank you very much !!

Comment: I have been using this trick for a few months, but it would appear this behavior is broken as of tk 8.6.12

Comment: @smp55 Try `tree.column(col, width=100, stretch=0)`.

Comment: That did it! Thank you! For others, you can put `stretch=0` either before or after calling `table.update()`.