# tkinter treeview with constant width

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

I have searched it online for a long time but can't find a result for that (I have found a lot of question about it and posts online, but none of them works or readable).

In my project I use `Sqlite3` to connect to a database, and I view it in a `ttk.TreeView`. My problem is that the tree view changes its width every time I load a new table.

I have tried to set the columns width when I load them but this is what I got:
[image: The current result]

This is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import db

table: ttk.Treeview
window: tk.Tk

def call_back_func(event):
    selected_table = event.widget.get()
    handler = db.SqlLiteHandler.get_instance()  # Some class that handles communication with sqlite
    cols_name = handler.get_columns_for(selected_table) # get the columns in the table
    all_data = handler.get_data_from_table(selected_table, columns_names=cols_name) # read data from table

    # Delete all rows in the table
    table.delete(*table.get_children())

    table['columns'] = cols_name # update the table's columns
    # a suggested solution I have found online
    for col in cols_name:
        table.column(col, width=0)

    window.update()

    for col in cols_name:
        table.heading(col, text=col.title())
        table.column(col, width=25, anchor=tk.W) # tried to set the width here

    for i, item in enumerate(all_data): # Insert the data
        table.insert('', tk.END, i, values=item)

def main():
    global table, window

    # Creating tkinter window and set dimensions
    window = tk.Tk()
    window.title('Sql Queries Gui')
    # Set the geometry
    window.geometry('800x650')
    # window.resizable(False, False)
    window.attributes('-topmost', 1)
    # Frame
    home_frame = tk.Frame(window)
    home_frame.config(bg="#e0f8f2")
    home_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.EW)
    # Set label

    tk.Label(home_frame, text="Select The Table:", font=("Calibri", 14), bg='#e0f8f2').grid(column=0, row=0,padx=5, pady=5)

    # Create Combobox
    handler = db.SqlLiteHandler.get_instance()
    tables_names = handler.table_names
    table_box = ttk.Combobox(home_frame,values = tables_names, width=27)
    table_box.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", call_back_func)
    table_box.grid(column=0, row=1, padx=5, pady=5)

    table = ttk.Treeview(home_frame, show="headings", height=20, selectmode=tk.BROWSE)
    table.grid(column=0, row=2)
    vertical_scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(home_frame, orient=tk.VERTICAL, command=table.yview)
    vertical_scrollbar.grid(column=1, row=2, sticky=tk.NS)
    table.configure(yscrollcommand=vertical_scrollbar.set)

    horizontal_scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(home_frame, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, command=table.xview)
    horizontal_scrollbar.grid(column=0, row=3, sticky=tk.EW)
    table.configure(xscrollcommand=horizontal_scrollbar.set)

    table_box.set(tables_names[0])

    window.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Have you tried using `table.grid(column=0, row=2, uniform=True)`?

Comment: @SylvesterKruin I get an error that `uniform` is not an option in `grid`

Comment: `width` option is in pixels (not characters) in `table.column()`.  So the result is expected.  What is your issue actually?

Comment: @acw1668 I know, the problem is that the table width also changes and doesn&#39;t match the columns&#39; total width.

Comment: When you reassign the `columns` option of a treeview which has already been managed by a layout manager, the width of the treeview will be recalculated with default width of 200 for each column.  The later change of the width of those columns will not affect the width of the treeview.  You can call `table.grid_remove()` before reassigning the `columns` option and then call `table.grid()` after updating the column widths.

Comment: @acw1668 Thank you it works, but can I limit the size of the table without squishing the columns' size¿ Because at it is, if I have a lot of columns they resize so the total width is the desired table width.

Comment: See my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64477453/how-to-view-partial-area-of-a-treeview-and-horizontal-scrollable-in-tkinter).

Comment: Amazing, thank you 